# How can I check if the following are possible states of a qubit?

Tags: quantum-state, nielsen-and-chuang

I would like to check if state

$$ |\psi\rangle =  \cos{\theta}|0\rangle + i \sin{\theta}|1\rangle
$$

is properly defined.

But when I calculated $\langle \psi | \psi \rangle$ is get
$$
\cos^2{\theta} - \sin^2{\theta}
$$

so I am facing sin and cos.

**What is wrong in my calculation?**

Comment: I want to make inner product of each state with itself to show the value is 1(valid state) or not. @MartinVesely

Comment: Yes right @MartinVesely

Comment: I deleted my comments because now I understand. Please find answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standard inner product on space $\mathbb{C}^{n}$ is defined as

$$
\langle a|b \rangle = \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{i}b_{i}^{\dagger},
$$

where $b^{\dagger}$ is complex conjugate (i.e. for $x \in \mathbb{C}$: if $x = x_{re} + ix_{im}$ then $x^{\dagger} = x_{re} - ix_{im}$).

In your case $a_{1} = \cos(\theta)$ and $a_{2} = i\sin(\theta)$. Since you are interested in product $\langle a|a \rangle$, $a_{1}^{\dagger} = \cos(\theta)$ because it is a real number and $a_{2}^\dagger = -i\sin(\theta)$ you have

$$
\langle a|a \rangle = a_{1}a_{1}^{\dagger}+a_{2}a_{2}^{\dagger} = \cos^{2}(\theta) -i^{2}\sin^{2}(\theta) = \cos^2(\theta) + sin^{2}(\theta) = 1 
$$

Alternatively you can use normalization condition $|a|^2+|b|^2 = 1$:

$$|a|^2 = |\cos(\theta)|^2 = \cos^{2}(\theta)$$

and

$$|b|^2 = |i\sin(\theta)|^2 = |i|^2|\sin^{2}(\theta)| = 1^2\cdot \sin^{2}(\theta)$$

And again you have $\cos^{2}(\theta) + \sin^{2}(\theta) = 1$.

**Overall, your  quatum state is properly defined.**

Answer (score 1):

You asked "What is wrong in my calculation?"

My guess is that your mistake is in forgetting that  $\langle \psi | = \cos{\theta}\langle 0| - i \sin{\theta}\langle 1|$ instead of $\cos{\theta}\langle 0| + i \sin{\theta}\langle 1|$ (because $i$ becomes $-i$ when you take the complex conjugate).